# Install php-imap on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS with php 7.1

Tags: php, ubuntu, imap

Ive tried adding the `ppa:ondrej/php` repository and installing but im still getting this error.

`sudo apt-get install php7.1-imap`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php7.1-imap
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.1-imap'
```

Its missing from this: `apt-cache search php7.1`

```
php7.1-cli - command-line interpreter for the PHP scripting language
php7.1-readline - readline module for PHP
php7.1-opcache - Zend OpCache module for PHP
php7.1-mysql - MySQL module for PHP
php7.1-zip - Zip module for PHP
php7.1-mbstring - MBSTRING module for PHP
php7.1-json - JSON module for PHP
php7.1-xml - DOM, SimpleXML, WDDX, XML, and XSL module for PHP
php7.1 - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (metapackage)
php7.1-gd - GD module for PHP
php7.1-curl - CURL module for PHP
libapache2-mod-php7.1 - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (Apache 2 module)
php7.1-common - documentation, examples and common module for PHP
```

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 14.04 is not longer supported by most PPA because its reached its end of life.

Use a newer ubuntu version, like 20.04 LTS. Also php7.1 has already reached end of life too. We already reached php8 now.

I recommend that you learn docker and refactor your code / install your app for php7.4 or php8 (whichever works with php imap) and ubuntu 20.04. I know, its a lot of work but its either this or get left in the dust :/

Comment: ahhh dang.. i would love to do this but i dont have the time. Is there a way to install imap from source ?

Comment: I can't find anything, its just all apt-get installs